Config facebook share properly in reactjs
I'm using react-share and react-helmet-async for facebook sharing in reactjs. I have configured meta tags and verified by SEO check in google chrome extension.

But in production, image not showing in sharing section.

What did I miss in meta tags? Any suggestion or hint would be helpful. Thank you.
